"The number of samples must be more than the number of classes." Error in LDA
I tried to implement LDA in the code below, and I got 'ValueError: The number of samples must be more than the number of classes.'
            results = {}
            for category in categorical_columns:
                lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=min(num_dimensions, len(data[category].unique()) - 1))
                reduced_data = lda.fit_transform(numerical_data, data[category])
                results[category] = reduced_data
            first_category = list(results.keys())[0]
            reduced_df = pd.DataFrame(results[first_category], columns=[f'component_{i}' for i in range(results[first_category].shape[1])])

Maybe this is cause by the high number of factors in test data. The dataset is a synthetic dataset, and it generates a new factor for each new row. This is what the data looks like:
ID,Name,Age,Country,Email,Phone,Address,Company,DateJoined,Salary
1,Name_1,22,Country_1,email_1@example.com,SGuFcH27FA,Address_1,Company_1,2020-01-01,35129
2,Name_2,29,Country_2,email_2@example.com,RkORvljDXH,Address_2,Company_2,2020-01-01,114835
3,Name_3,57,Country_3,email_3@example.com,UzmTzGu2JL,Address_3,Company_3,2020-01-01,50936
4,Name_4,65,Country_4,email_4@example.com,wMcMulQB2r,Address_4,Company_4,2020-01-01,86668
5,Name_5,27,Country_5,email_5@example.com,HFRo0x4wfH,Address_5,Company_5,2020-01-01,110978

I understand LDA is not fit for these type of data, and it would require more measurements per factor to calculate an meaningful covariance matrix. But for the code above, the number of classes should be equal to the number of samples, and I don't understand why this error occurred.
